# How to make an Android Studio Project (Java) code be compiled for compatibility with Cross Platform devices?

Tags: java, android, cross-platform

Is it possible for an Android Studio Project to be Cross Platform compatible? 
Or is it possible only with C# languages for Xamarin or other cross platform tools where Java is not the primary language.

I am a Java Developer and just dived in Android and want to build Cross Platform compatible apps using Java (or use the same Android Project code).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use model-view-controler pattern you can do it but in different projects.

If you abstract all the code that doesn't belong to the view you can copy it in other project and compile it with javac instead of with the android SDK. But you still have to make the view for the two projects.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is yes and no. It really depends on how advanced your android app is. There are options if its a simple hello world, but anything that is difficult will have to be rewritten in the native language of the OS. 
Here take a look at this post there are some helpful hint there
[how to make android app compatible with multiple platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650195/how-to-make-android-app-compatible-with-multiple-platforms?rq=1)

cheers